# Network unreachable

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

I wanted to try Ubuntu so I did a dual boot installation with Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my new computer. When I start Windows, the computer runs fine, I can access the internet via my router. When I start Ubuntu I can't access the internet or ping the router.

When I ping the router i get this message:

```
unreachable network
```

I have been googling this problem and tried:

```
sudo add default gw 192.168.1.2   (router ip)
```

which gave me a strange fault message.

I am using an ethernet connection although my router has wifi. 
The ethernet connection goes from/to motherboard and router. I bought the motherboard, CPU and memory and case and all the parts necessary. I have installed both Windows and Ubuntu myself.

The parts are new, for example the motherboard: Asus Z97-pro

btw Ubuntu used to work until a made some changes ,(one change was to upgrade the BIOS of the computer, because the old BIOS was unstable in Windows.)

I am not sure what motherboard drivers you mean. On the Asus webpage there are a few drivers for Windows. That's all I can find.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:c3:7b:95:24:ae  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:df800000-df820000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:139111 (139.1 KB)  TX bytes:139111 (139.1 KB)
```

Comment: How do you connect to the router? By wire or wireless?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your problem

The problem is described here:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/internet#TOC-No-wired-or-wireless-internet-on-a-dual-boot-computer

> This may be due to a flaw in Windows, which can be repaired easily.
>
> If you have a dual bootable PC with Windows, and you've just used Windows, you may not get an IP address after a reboot in Linux. And so no internet connection.
>
> This has the following reason: every network card has a unique MAC address. This address is ingrained in your NIC. The DHCP server in your router remembers this MAC address.
>
> When you access the internet in Windows and then reboot in Linux, in many cases you'll get no IP address from the DHCP server in your router. Because this server will recall that it previously issued an IP address for that very same MAC address, and won't issue a new one.
>
> You can solve this by forcing Windows to release the IP address, before you reboot the PC. By the way: Linux by default does release the IP address on shutdown. So a reboot from Linux into Windows causes no problems.
>
> Tip: Did you forget to force Windows to release the IP address, and you don't want to boot Windows to do it as yet? Then simply boot Ubuntu or Linux Mint twice in a row. After the second boot of Ubuntu or Mint you can probably connect.
>
> A. Manual method
>   1. Open a DOS window in Windows
>
> Windows XP:
>   Start - Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt
>
> Windows 7:
>   Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt
>
> 2. Type:
>      ipconfig /release
>
> (note the space between ipconfig and /release)
>
> And press Enter.
>
> B. Semi-automatic method
>   By means of a shortcut on your desktop, you can apply a semi-automatic solution for this.
>
> 1. Open Notepad
>      Windows XP: Start - Programs - Accessories - Notepad
> 2. type the following text:
>      ipconfig /release
> 3. Save this text file as release.bat and place it on your desktop. Now you can always simply double click this file, before you exit Windows.
>
> As I said, Linux releases the IP address by default on shutdown. So a reboot from Linux into Windows causes no problems.